# What was Admiral Ackbar's name?

Tags: star-wars, names

I saw references in some newer Disney canon to Admiral Ackbar's first name being Gial.

1. What was the history of the name Gial (as in, how and when did it appear in canon)?
2. More importantly, **what was his first name - if any was stated - in prior canon**, including various EU/Legends levels?

Comment: I was going to make a joke but noticed it's already been done http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Admiral_Snackbar

Comment: his nickname might be (its a) Trapper :-)

Comment: Admiral Gial "It's a Trap!" Ackbar

Comment: It better not be "Sheev"...

Answer (score 33):

His name is **Gial Ackbar** in both Expanded Universe and new Disney Canon.

Gial is simply a name he was referred to in [*The Essential Guide to Warfare*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Warfare) in 2012 and his Expanded Universe canon, and transferred to Disney Canon in [*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) in 2015.

Answer (score 28):

### Gial, or possibly "Ernie"

The first reference to his forename seems to have been in [The Essential Guide to Warfare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Warfare)

> ***Gial Ackbar*** was born into a prominent merchant clan in the city of
>   Foamwander, served his planet's king during the Clone Wars, and held
>   high military and political office m the early years of the Imperial
>   era. At first. Ackbar saw the New Order as restoring Republic law and
>   justice—but the Empire soon brought an invasion fleet to his
>   homeworld. The peaceful cultural and technological achievements of Dac
>   had to be suppressed to preserve the idea of human superiority.

This name was then canonised in the *index* of [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)

> *Admiral **Gial** Ackbar - P171*

---

Interestingly, in the excellent [Making of Star Wars: Return of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Making_of_Return_of_the_Jedi) we learn that Lucas and the crew would refer to the Ackbar puppet on the dailies as ***Ernie*** Ackbar.

> Main unit next moved to Stage 5 and the rebel briefing room, which
>   meant first days for Blakiston, Crowley, and Tim Rose (Ackbar, or,
>   sometimes, “Ernie” Ackbar, on the Progress Reports). In wide shots,
>   Ackbar was a man in a suit; in closeup, a puppeteer would manipulate
>   his facial movements from below. Although still “immersed” in
>   Poltergeist, Richard Edlund arrived to oversee the VistaVision shots
>   on that set because, in postproduction, a hologram of the Death Star
>   was to be added by the Computer Division.

Comment: He certainly seems more like an Ernie than a Gial.